# Continuity of Kneading invariants of generalised $\beta$-trasformations

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, symbolic-dynamics

For $\beta \in (1,2]$ and $\alpha \in [0,2-\beta]$ consider the generalised $\beta$-transformation $T_{\alpha,\beta}:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ to be $$T_{\alpha, \beta}(x) = \beta x + \alpha \mod 1.$$ It is a well known fact that for each $\beta \in (1,2]$ and $\alpha \in [0,2-\beta]$ there exists a pair of sequences $a = (a_i), b = (b_i) \in \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ satisfiying that $a_1 = 1$, $b_1 = 0$ and
\begin{equation}\label{lex}
\begin{split}
&\sigma(a) \preccurlyeq \sigma^n(a) \prec \sigma(b); \\
&\sigma(a) \prec \sigma^n(b) \preccurlyeq \sigma(b) \quad \text{for all} \quad n \in \mathbb{N},
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $\prec$ stands for the lexicographic order in $\left\{0,1\right\}^{\mathbb{N}}$. A pair $(a,b)$ satisfying the pevious condition is called *lex-admissible*. Then it is possible to define a map $K:\Delta \to \mathcal{L}$ by $K(\alpha,\beta) = (a,b)$ where
$$\Delta = \left\{(\beta,\alpha): \beta \in (1,2] \quad \text{and} \quad \alpha \in [0,2-\beta]\right\}$$ and $$\mathcal{L} = \left\{(a,b) \in \left\{0,1\right\}^{\mathbb{N}} \times \left\{0,1\right\}^{\mathbb{N}}:(a,b) \quad \text{is lex admissible} \right\}.$$ Following the works of Glendinning in *Topological conjugation of Lorenz maps by $\beta$-transformations.* Math. Proc. Cambridge Philos. Soc. 107 (1990), no. 2, 401–413, and  Barnsley, Steiner, and Vince in *Critical itineraries of maps with constant slope and one discontinuity.* Math. Proc. Cambridge Philos. Soc. 157 (2014), no. 3, 547–565. it seems that the map is injective but not surjective. I would like to know if there is a reference adressing this.

Also, I want to ask is if there is a reference where it is studied the continuity of the map $K^{-1}: K(\Delta) \to \Delta$. Following the results by Parry contained in *On the $\beta$-expansions of real numbers.* Acta Math. Acad. Sci. Hungar. 11 (1960), 401–416. it is possible to show the continuity of the map $K^{-1}$ when it is restricted to the elements of $\Delta$ where $a = 0^\infty$. However, I haven't found a reference addressing the general case yet.

EDIT: The inverse map $K^{-1}: K(\mathcal{\Delta}) \to \Delta$ can be defined implicitly by following the results of Li, Sahlsten and Samuel *Intermediate $\beta$-shifts of finite type.* Discrete Contin. Dyn. Syst. 36 (2016), no. 1, 323–344. as follows:

Consider $(a,b) = K(\alpha,\beta)$ and the symbolic space $$\Sigma_{a,b} = \left\{(x_i) \in \left\{0,1\right\}^{\mathbb{N}}: \sigma(a) \preccurlyeq \sigma^n((x_i)) \preccurlyeq \sigma(b) \text{ for all }n \geq 0\right\}.$$ Then $$\pi_{\alpha,\beta}((x_i)) = \dfrac{\alpha}{1-\beta} + \mathop{\sum}\limits_{i=1}^\infty \dfrac{x_i}{\beta^i}.$$ As $\pi_{a,b}(\sigma(a)) = 0$ and $\pi_{a,b}(\sigma(b)) = 1$ then the system $$0 = \alpha/(1-\beta) + \mathop{\sum}\limits_{i=1}^\infty a_{i+1} \cdot \beta^{-i} \quad  \text{and} \quad 1 = \alpha/(1-\beta) + \mathop{\sum}\limits_{i=1}^\infty b_{i+1} \cdot \beta^{-i}$$ defines $K^{-1}$.

Thanks in advance for your help.